# Change background color and text color of a PDFView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, pdf, colors, pdfview

It is my first question in here, so please tell me if you need more context. 
I am using a PDFView in my app by compiling this : compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.6.1'.

I am capable of showing up my black and white PDF in my app ( I placed them in assets folder and I only call them by their name in my program ; for example : "file.pdf" ). Now I just need to change the colors of the background and the text.

Can someone help me get through it please ?

Comment: Welcome on SO!
Can you provide a link to the `PDFView` lib you're using?

Comment: Yes, there it is : https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer . Thanks for your attention

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? If yes, can you please share the answer as I am also having trouble with this?

Answer (score 0):

add line: `android:background="@color/....."` in pdfview in your xml file for change background color.